# Error occurred while populating metadata while reading items from S/4 using java cloud sdk VDM

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

*Using java SAP Cloud SDK version 3.9.0*

We have a code snippet for reading Outbound Delivery Items from S/4 while looks like this:

```
List<OutbDeliveryItem> items = new DefaultOutboundDeliveryV2Service()
                    .getAllOutbDeliveryItem()
                    .filter(OutbDeliveryItem.DELIVERY_DOCUMENT.eq("someDocument"))
                    .execute(someDestination);
```

The code executes successfully and is able to read the items from S/4. But below exception always gets logged:

```
ERROR com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache - Error occurred while populating metadata: 
com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 401.
Logon failed. 401 Not authorized. 
Full error message: 
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><title>Logon failed</title><style>body { background: #ffffff; text-align:
 center; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }.content { display: table; position:absolute; width:100%; height:80%; }.valigned { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }.lowerCenter { display: table-
cell; vertical-align: bottom; }.footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: -1; }.footerLeft { float: left; margin-left: 20px; }.footerRight { float: right; margin-right: 20px; positio
n: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; }.centerText { font-style: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 26px; color: #444444; z-index: 1; }.errorTextHeader { font-style: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 40
px; color: #444444; }.bottomText { align: center; font-style: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: #444444; }.biggerBottomText { align: center; font-style: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 1
6px; color: #444444; }.detailTable { align: bottom; vertical-align: middle; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; font-style: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; color: #444444; }</style></head><body><di
v class="content"><div class="valigned"><p class="centerText"><span class="errorTextHeader"> 401 Not authorized </span></p></div></div><div class="footer"><div class="footerLeft"><img width='150' height='80' tit
le='' alt='SAP logo'src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAABQCAYAAAGMt7zdAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAFhpJREFUeNpiZEAAJiBmZCAd/IdhmGYWhu0ffzNQAjz5mVigTGa291/JNudXlBQHA5K3
2P////8DWQHv9LsMnzOVGWTm3mf4+OsfmI0sBwNfslQ4gdRPkDeZkA24/OoHg1DHFTCGaX6SrMjA+vE7mA0SBwEQH4SRDUI2h120+sx/GDh67xOYhokhy8H4QD0cuCKMfcXJl/8lCo7+xwYevf0BpkHyIIzPIFiYYQDp9AP/Vx17jsLHZxBMkE02cc9PQrH2eL4L1jBCN4wZaiMzDlv
/gVIAFP/HZRlAADEi0YzUyAGMYFdt//iNgtTPCiT/sMAMIzcHAFM/PzQY4BlcCDkWeabdwcqG8WEYqE8AGs5wg+AAlvphKR6W2mFyM868BecMaOoXBAp/BuK/DGhFD4rLPnz/8x8fQHcRA7zogQLJwmNg+nm/FQM/B4Y6uPyLCdZYXYTTZbDUDsJoqR+rixjQ0hc/MAe8J5D68boI2T
A2UP7EkWj/Qw34gc8gEAAIIEY07zJBvcHEQF/wD4r/wnITC5IDQWwO5vWvPzIMAPgbKMqNFKIMLGjRAKyjILn9W6IcXJPFxhcMl979gvN3eorD2e7bX2IVP/TiB0PrecJ+/J4kLwiN2t/QUPuPHJWgqAOVIdzAxPkWpsl79SOGLEMhBm8VHgb+/ptgsUwjQYYOezEUw2FyHwvVwfSRJ
98Y5PhYwRhdDQx8KtLA6iCMfIkNbA2FhJpI00UGmBUwR4HE3tTpg9k5WjwMM0++gesLmHcbTMPkwSXPZ0j9/rbeAK+DsOVzUE4SEi898R+G8QGQfPeuJyh8bODjtz9gOWj5gK++wporsUYluUA65zCc/WyqHUkhhCsq/8um7qc4h4F8+WSOE1kOQnfYf6jm30y//1LkqEcLXQWg7RCy
HIStgIUVGeQ2tpE9+J9cB8EAQAAx4mgHMVDgOFI9gt6GQnEAclXESMcC/z9SVfQPvSpiBjbufjIMFPDkZ8daPzL/+DUg7vm/ZbbsP7RcCG9LM3//TXcH/V3dpfRv/YR3yDkWucxiZP4BcdQsW2GGGBVuMHvzo+8M4XtfoxgEq5g3P/zGMOXaZ4zKGgQW3/7CsOQO/ub579VtKn+3z3y
NrbJmhHVjgM3sz8idT/ROKrhfmaTIwM/OhCGOSx96JxYGfq7vUvm9e9ZLaNfoD3ofAQ6QDc7c+RyM4Qp//AFjZAchiyMDUAsCGSiwMcLVgfCvNe04HYS39bDy/FsUGlfr+1GWCoNi/3UUMb8l98D0uwodMD3dVZzBb9l9SJTdO+34a99cnA5iwNc8BhkIwlM9pRiYfv0FY5gl4Ab+B0
hO5WdnBsuhGApVD1f7/ieY//fmCccvs5PO4HMQA1pzmQd92AB9CAEGZh59gcLHpw8mLxAzwwFkB7QTwkSomoEndGBb6DO8LNMWZJgfrwZX+PH7XwZ+TkgkSpSdhHTQuswJZnmQ2l+Pzjm+X5lFVAhhOEqi4OhnWSF2hsfvEAU7qOdIKoD1KsG97yfnHN+tySXaQRgJfWKEMkOYuTjlb
StoM+jn0/OO7zbkk+QgDEcx/sPe4vj0/Q8DHydEqUzGQRS5JzPsMYP/zz+Gv19e5b4lw0EY0SeTsu8zVaoOoIOer4hYQI6D0Fug/xn//qPcQV+BDloVRbaDYI6CxdlfXNFHtIO+vcl5thruoL/kOAi9kccM7eGwkDgC9x9p3OAvNHTIdhC2gRBqDAmS3WmAAYAAYsST+LGxhzNA7vCg
szGKKka0mGRGGt5iwtH5GcoBgzEYjTSk9g8tJf7H1qpCHvtjYdr87jPDCAP/962Q+t+f9RaaILAOYKGnGnBgDUQ3Z6DA33X9Cv9WdLxFGlX+j6/FwIiOB6qjSk/wewWwy7dt+hukWukvUjbEWWZhFPSwntS1CBkGeV4Woix/+PkPg9W6ZwwffiFqQj1hNobjQVJY1XPPfoAh9jVVgWj
PHn7+g8FjywvSA2ktsNe3c9ZbaCD9YUAb/seWshixDKPB2g9sDz/+eos8SE0MaD/5jqH9FOrA6qdcVZzqL7/5yWC9/BHR6vEBvsm3Car5ualL5deeOSQFEjEpiwFbQAn0XMeqFtTHB6m//PonSk/vQ4kmXsfrirAz2ImxMRx5jH8yFN1ebOZ2WgkzVO5/iVX/j609Kj8PzCMrkAh253
EBkCNBeJmfNIMg4z8G5p9/wPjLp18M1558hfNBGKQGHVTtfoYhtiVcHkUfNoAsD8IzTr3BUKMHDHh0df9uHHf8WKolCAwoUCj+gDbhfyMFGNGNVbzZUKTu3NvXjYZEB2TX/ucM3Qcg5YeOBCfD/kwNDDWi9ecZPDX4GRZFKmGVAwFsdh598AVuLrZpYBAw6r8KH5P59eCM46dFaRcoS
UkkBZZYBaLwkRVgZ9ibr43TochArfEcw616Iwxx8crTcPbLdlPMEbOzbxjy1tzHKkeMnR9//GX49eis44dlmVQNJKICS6LoON4pMNAQzqlqQwZqAtPW8wynCZh59dlXhh1X3jP07HyCKLifnHN8vyqbJoFEVAHP+Ocvw7OJ1nD+7IPPGHZeegfnz0vRoHq7B1dASeUfxRrToDGyt+vy
aBpIRKUsakyugoBl7SmGx28hU9CWagIMVx9/AQ+NgYfBptkRZYZM1iHUdtKb2wGvVqccpEcgEZOy/sumHQAztGV5GOrDVcAexcgSQI+nTLvC8AQYGKtKDDDkn7z5wfDk5Td4rJy49g4llrQLjjDMydIhHKt//iFGypaFL6FnIBFKWaBAZJNN2vtu0PTdgIH0bGXkgAQStjFS9OEKioc
nqRNIr3Ofro5cjDSqSPdAwpUNYWM6IEf9///rW/t/0JrD//+YGP6jrMClIWD8z8AItPL394tP10RtRurY/mVAXZVA95hkxDFKir7kgtwhXUoG5v5jCZwBCSRCI56MBAKU1qOXuEY0BxQABCDnbGPiKMI4/hy2VbHF3oEGUoRaWzTUQqvYKi8lUioRIaZqDLSiidooUWPsB0Pa2jQxIl
XAGotNq1ibmFJiNNE2FkrsBxUuMVYjLEZrscLdQSkv5a5SetzerTdz3b293ZnZO3p3e+k9yeRgdmZ297czz8zO/GcNMQJKt4nRUB7OPI3eMZ4WK4DQzAXWTCkQfFXCdQ6M5iNBa6ZUhKMM11MtEygjAOHqvVGnbeZRB6cnZEL9eDLB0wvlxjzwr+5Iqzy0BYuEBN4df6A8nl7P4ynrQ
nk3xE3PEG+w3O4+91Op+aGM4KXmmODyxBEonnNVLymkDH6ZS2G4KcZNzfKCmq3JKFI4dkGrZgX0cnHhs3ieu/L8netBvbhKfLWizWcZxPkj0SozboYda26FHNOCgPjB/3ho6b8kCYFJhsTENSsWquLlu31EUwqJledC4ccRJ94RdG01ysXNbF1eTABFXe0xEMZXeC4r8eC5KXSgKO0m
6KhIDfoa3jRPQgvnCIijrTBXnbyAFdfBpKXZQ18PQ+/EbMigLtdmFYN/bswtm/bx0F53qOuGqBm+mr0oJFDIco3zcV55oNnRR24POi3NkCzg4PpkVTm0YHA65wSKCQs1wz0FySFffG3XeZxXDG1lbL2sPK2y6QdrW+5eBDneh6QsSxWcs9z0a/fMCRQTVlt5GjH+SL8db/JDocE8Dna
n/wY3f2tTXWDFsoXMG93+gFET1pDDheX9Som/3LqrMjRAOblLb2TPGRTLwcNjd6lvcv/pyQAtQffgNDR0+3Z/1OWnwHdnHAFd6qrbbtSsFXUPpkDDT2PMNEe4KWjo8S/X195ngndL1DWWKh32+ih7Xe41gWLWLGITu98EmbfcQPQF7/0wqoo7XpUZVLlaPgutBcjTHPh5TLMcyUe5eH
s4QDFhcaPk9+jfa7Pwfo/qlYu9T1JgBrQHRGkkQccXT2RIecjvbOqyiVCVaXi3fWp7zrJwgGLCqmk/x8zYUpkOEztW4VCYnoibgDy8nGdS5UGijZ0dNlV8eVaSlI8IQRACyt5XsYQCS3YNPG+/+NbqsIFi+izrhBO48zNYtaJl3zzn26MlqmCQvVOmvqFn2/6hAkH+DZ2PZNW5JijI9
PnQgqX0DkMqW/DYx9/OCyso9tDBe+KSfX/A+6eGgy4MSYVYNaTfNo2PHf1VrQpAEiRavjsWL8CQWKA2tf4l1ahIgNKEhUJjlw1LhZAcKBj7e+dqOLxZrb1CciCxzF3HBolA5roRhhu5DD1nHUjIYh+rXxsRUEHBEsPr7QN4q1nWrtPQ/gu9q0f6rUezjar4xpNWqSzHNFkyXrUm9EEw
epilH/RhUBf2rIsYKOa7Yeo285RWZqTNQhqtaFvPgAOaOq3410dAsI8250cUFNPBg8d3jq9euReebOGISTr6JmFrcVrE4TR1WKCx00I+KHhBfVgYcVBMWGgguHfLCshfnoQ3ZaJNmk0nhsB6dbNmWY4pKqDEWyWKVLygRj4qigooNiyvb3l6rf+DLqi5IXh6mDjOUoIa/rg4aqCYsPY
+kxW2k4iqPbQJFgnjzGd87rAsNxlaX1oZRM0SVDXLtj+6oJi9YfOxf0MqqPn4IDF+95cD+HUFBdQLmv+8KP3f+dt40M1QzIOCF1RytEGxR/BjMyDKJLdVLoUXNqRDUqI6eev3VtjdfhanEWtMwPEuC3MJm5RHdS3jM1LNsn7ysC6gWEOH+ekvntLls15MaJ+W6AZKWbMEZW8YS2b5bI
OuoGjN0LcEJMQOLMuhUt1BkWBJq7CGGGE19HmpCQK39OsCilazfGtnMVCzhg5vNMoA6QqK5LOkXegCf6VewCplj09Z4/uN+PATKZXRNVjbNtWDX6UsVyrrAkreG4p/6yVmUyrt5GConw7QG5Z8GKGXTFKpZFGKNWJG2h0LAlzWVzt0daSxJO0OSWath/0vQHvnAtPUFcbxr4ibBge4I
auCj/meyEx0m8NFo9lDdGbrTJzC5syyIU50btMQM7vFbOiyqWTL1IE6dUF8MB9RAR9xusWo+IAxKD6CKAIFRbAtFIb09t71HKSW9j7O7W0L9N4vOWnpfZ/74zvfPe33/1QS6OPb3t9/Cu5vxhCOJaTb8QJAIlKqEgGbYt0HLIbwlROuQIK5CHAaFwNYxktVJwwHinlvKGVTEuPaRgUE
WU58UDknHgawwCUUlCmgdf7wxhfQcjXaaRuVEFyBBPGUI0RtmRc5BrNy3+SCJ10EeblvMinzDWKg5RsK2VKlcQugaKXD/Z4nazFzancss+lz4yOPpRLzxEmiSucCl8piVXreX42miukjm2fRu1IMIEEUIlAg/mHzXCpZZmz6u4eyUjrrgQ1v0wftZR1ogtiLc2gkCd5dlquUodB/zGr
RUfvXv2M9utEArt910O5ARTLdwPqZ2OTWKeperJ8jvVfHgmOK+dAoSkcd/FFD5aYhoJzzUZ1fub4nck/KlQsutuA95IkASIoKhg9GBsHgPoGSrhkVTEWpmrtKm7AIMKldnRtBfGx0jAEZlUTrNn082KP3FKWQnr3bAht1jVBhpnzuoVoPrddQx9P5PBTbl46ivjbiml1nexrs0d6C0s
rseRFJ0SFYm9fbFpVZgZOiuSx9aj+cmSnGssubYd4JYeVqc+JQr1/f2isGWJtv8CJQlK718AaN5eQWoSGPlgKUJLD6bCytnxzRG3I1EV7vcJQdG5VR3iFL1tneHx0Maa+Fu7X/RX/WQub1Bt51GpOG+8yhfH/5Aay99MCzQB1N1bSe2uoToCSBtehkTf2vb6i93skoHTp6B3+q46DgQ
Cj+SJpHid5xy3Ysbm9oWjYSfGk5ZWaIz66WtA/GNuQ9zPlJ03p6m0+BkgSWscVa71wCj93bWGFWVgUU1wqXjkQFet8a/hTER4Xgv5F8PtpWMF5JGAZi6x+wAfzC1jLO5cblZKrRSH/AMdXdDn9IT1gZE2a/NhJbfLwGaxuIn4ey6FqO/ax5eOa3TgHK3eAdtFptCAlU+IaZLDgjiiTL
MvdGA25JOXreR1NH2zRzgGSo2rxeT9g8XQ1JudK8hIpmWK8V9QG6LtT+TRyBQROy+DHBsKdIRMzF0KbWwmPTmvcm3+lMoNpNdM2KlJQU4n+j6PBeUL5sNBiSx8DmGf1tT2w9bB1v9UhDHR8/NlTwHIrvteAmeCNt+0L7ZDsWubdgBM+bFBY8XJD0BUWZrKV504wro4faoEJxA+XUHOW
VrYSAgc89FrK0i3WwaGKYqG3iovvi5uqlTLiZWsgnXQeF9oRNsyKJ1l1ypG04/TtBOE5C+zx/uxEqjO5V+cJpkBQj0A+hhB5IaF+0yVKer2nc/klRV/BQHgFLe6wKd2LiK/0kHXzmqGDcAAbaP0MFYlYd13PKXyA7Mn8Y0f7T8+5Dib7Z/p7kfDPmDIGpaTfcuyCOoRDJhqyJjeBVoX
AJDa6ZOEKINqAafl/YJYGSFLyHafPxPBYSbPhl9mCY8XyoV07u3G0zLNhdhtUy2g0dj0TsAYncjN/QUSLg5qpxREWC0i/Ugjb3cU2a+9+N9+lT4Tmb19RsL3WJoSwVBRpTRmKXBsrtGAuT56DysSDjJoR/dQUmrCuCvQV1Hj25V5/rg2FInqrGx4sb15dYQUSbXeGicPJ1dgXRtokx4
diT8mnoeMtQH7679YaDMpPVRN26PK1uzUtDbVAVdpUYyiseKzz5omCdIlRBPXZMX1xdHTWptv6UHla8TjYhi8uLZd1iXbbzwxHE5zNydT6uBn/vh5e9fiN01c0we8s1fLxHLJhaKws0xj2Lu4WH8ghYz67Ic7sAFhqKEiarYeHk/hDcu4fXLqzBdoN01U0dY50BQaKOiSSAZqddg7vr
Jnrl/JAu1JazNVBpaO04bVD1j8awL6lbAiUJLPUX5z1SWS1hSn/4VjMEurIhjanl0yOJ1+WUXRJ+CsRAPdi/pFsDJempsF0IAykcXfxmgv3zrEu1uCHpOCGLigiCFYQ3rDNtuZhzZBESIprY1Bdq6g8s9QugJIJFQ+TTvTpAhQzJajlKa8nOMFg04apMG1CHPvMroCSBhcQw81a/2KU
uZNsZPS5YGjsuzAb9kzDwGfYfF6J1Sqqa4EKpEWJGhNrW99xPftDcHlgZwSHvYbUNqMPL/BIoSTGWp6rXespKqswwfU2BW9teTZ2ENfQ8Yak5dzhl6JBZzbVL7+6as9ufgZLisZiBiX/hN5E2r/DeJDXMiVHj91LtRGEdrM66CTGjQiF1AXkdalRRmHQIcrYvd16HbZ+O9UxvcgyFVJ
MNqMy5sgDKXY+FXyMTTgv+Eg2BhoYj/BrWUQm9pLIRGpopIv3D7mzIQ9XsmScroIQ8FgOuv1phHgfvwjvW32/BjZRqvwIKlQDfK0+g+MByLAepYl3OMKAYB1D74mQNFBtYXF7KpakUsFxiqOqseAUokcG7q+qIAtYjD1W3VP9HXCbwp0/JCiiSGMv5b9r/u4MQqP/qk/RZ8zKd4GGDS
XZA8cXPctPHYgiW8+lIcaWhyxIoIARArop+fNKJXJCxLZetj1c0SMVBJkabU9ZBg6KaLH6IZET+rYDlwfX9GSyp68rC/gcKtRRHC4+EWgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='></div><div class="footerRight"><p class="bottomText"><span class="biggerBottomText">&c
opy;</span>2020 SAP SE, All rights reserved.</p></div></div></body></html>
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:117)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:97)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:33)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:219)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:239)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:156)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadMetadata(ODataQuery.java:379)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:310)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:253)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:151)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:135)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:250)
```

I examined our destination setup on Cloud Foundry and the setup on cloud connector as well. The setup is correct. If it was a problem with the setup, then the code would not have been able to read the items from S/4.

Upon debugging the sdk code a bit, I found a method `com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.OdataQuery.execute()` while tries to execute the read request 2 times. First time the read fails as the code is not able to fetch metadata and throws the exception that I've mentioned earlier in my question. Second time the read is successful (Code is able to read the metadata). I could have pasted the code snippet from sdk here but I am not sure if it is appropriate to do so.

I have following questions:

1. Is something wrong with my code? *(I suppose not since it is able to read the items from S/4)* If something is wrong, then what is it?
2. Is this a bug in sdk? If yes then when will it be fixed?
3. If this is something internal to sdk, which I shouldn't be worried about then how can I stop this exception from being logged? I have to get rid of the error log since it will generate false alerts in our production system.

Please let me know if you require any more info.

P.S.: I have seen a lot of comments on [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/19/deep-dive-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-s4hana-connectivity-made-simple/) from people facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this problem here. Can you pls retry with the latest Cloud SDK version (3.12.0 as of today)? Once updating to 3.12.0 also pls execute `mvn dependendy:tree` and tell us which version of the Maven artifacts under the group id `com.sap.cloud.servicesdk` you see. Moreover, can you pls link the exact blog comment in your question? I went through the blog and could not find any comment that revealed to refer to the same problem.

Comment: Hi, were you able to try the latest Cloud SDK version (which is now 3.14.0)?  If so, are you still facing the same problem?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I did  not get time to check. Will update once I have a look at it.

Comment: Hi, The issue seems to have gone away in version 3.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved as of SAP Cloud SDK version `3.11.0`.